# How to deal with multicollinearity in metafor in r

Tags: r, metafor

I am using `metafor` package for my meta-analysis. As part of the meta-analysis, I did a meta-regression analysis where I found out there is a multicollinearity issue across the variables I used. Is there any way to deal with it in `metafor` package?

I was suggested to use `bayesian model averaging (BMA)`. I am doing an ecological meta-analysis where my effect size is computed with `response ratio (treatment/control`, in such case, is it still possible to use `BMA`?

Comment: If you need advice choosing appropriate statistical models for your data, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. You are likely to get better help there. This is not really a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you, I will post in Cross Validated